# pandas dataframe insert to MongoDB as embedded document (list of Directories)

Tags: pandas, mongodb, dataframe, pymongo

my dataframe before inserting to MongoDB is like below,

```
    code    trade_date  open    high    low     close   pre_close   change  pct_chg     vol     
0   600111  20210308    58.99   59.16   56.58   56.66   58.52   -1.86   -3.1784     299902.37   
1   600111  20210305    58.00   58.91   57.71   58.52   59.31   -0.79   -1.3320     281584.57   
2   600111  20210304    60.31   61.60   58.96   59.31   58.67   0.64    1.0908  621415.96   
3   600111  20210303    58.21   58.80   57.80   58.67   58.49   0.18    0.3077  235677.52
```

I have extracted Year & Month from trade_date and appended a new column "trade_month" as below,

```
code    trade_date  open    high    low     close   pre_close   change  pct_chg     vol    trade_month
0   600111  20210308    58.99   59.16   56.58   56.66   58.52   -1.86   -3.1784     299902.37  202103
1   600111  20210305    58.00   58.91   57.71   58.52   59.31   -0.79   -1.3320     281584.57  202103
```

How can I insert this table to Mongodb in below format (embedded mongodb document including the whole month trade data as a list of dictionary)  via Pymongo please ?

```
{
  'code':'600111', 
  'trade_month':'202103',
  {'month_records': 
    [
      {'trade_date':'20210301','open':'123', 'high':'123',...},
      {'trade_date':'20210302','open':'123', 'high':'123',...},
      {'trade_date':'20210303','open':'123', 'high':'123',...},
      ...
    ] 
  }
}
```

I want to have a month's records as a single MongoDB document is aligning with my MongoDB schema design because I normally retrieve 1 month data via code and trade_date which would be indexed in MongoDB.

I did some research on my own for nearly 2 days, and did not find any clues on how to achieve that. Appreciate if any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use groupby at `code` and `month` level and aggregate to dict.

```
df.groupby(['code', 'trade_month']).apply(
    lambda x: x.to_dict(orient='records')
    ).rename('month_records').reset_index().to_dict('records')
```

Output:

```
[
   {
      "code":600111,
      "trade_month":202103,
      "month_records":[
         {
            "code":600111,
            "trade_date":20210308,
            "open":58.99,
            "high":59.16,
            "low":56.58,
            "close":56.66,
            "pre_close":58.52,
            "change":-1.86,
            "pct_chg":-3.1784,
            "vol":299902.37,
            "trade_month":202103
         },
         {
            "code":600111,
            "trade_date":20210305,
            "open":58.0,
            "high":58.91,
            "low":57.71,
            "close":58.52,
            "pre_close":59.31,
            "change":-0.79,
            "pct_chg":-1.332,
            "vol":281584.57,
            "trade_month":202103
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: Hi Raghava, much appreciate your help, it works perfectly. I did spend few mins to look up all methods / functions used in your solution in pandas official documents to understand how it works inside out. Happy to learn something new to me.